# What can I do with chicken rib meat?

Tags: chicken, culinary-uses

When I buy packaged chicken breast at the grocery, I get the untrimmed ones because they're significantly cheaper, and trimming fat isn't a problem for me. But the rib meat that comes attached is connected by a rather large chunk of fat. I always end up cutting the whole thing off and throwing it out, with the rib meat. Is there anything I can really do with this meat so I'm not wasting it? Once in a while I'll throw it in the pan anyway, and then eat it myself when it cooks (which is way before the rest is done). But could I save them, maybe freeze them in a bag until I have enough to do something? Are there any other ideas?

Comment: Make soup stock!

Comment: You may also consider the fat for preparing schmatlz! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmaltz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save in a bag in your freezer along with all chicken bones you come across.  Cleave through the bones to expose some collagen before freezing (consider [roasting](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8897/how-can-i-roast-chicken-bones-without-meat) all ingredients before hand).  Add whatever vegetable bits you don't use in your cooking - including things you wouldn't eat (but nothing poisonous) to your bag, especially onions (including skin and root), celery, and carrots.

When you have a good amount, put in a pot and just cover with cold water.  A bit of vinegar helps promote a nice gelling of your broth.  Tomato paste, peppercorns, and a bay leaf will add to the flavor.  Simmer gently for around five hours.  Remove.  If you had fat still on your meat you may want to chill until the fat rises to the surface to remove the fat.

Your broth will keep 3 to 4 days in the fridge or it can be frozen until you have a recipe which calls for chicken stock or broth.  Your homemade broth will be an excellent addition to sauces, a great base for soups, or an excellent liquid for cooking rice, couscous, or quinoa.

Comment: A couple of allspice berries go well in a stock pot, as well.

Answer (score 2):

Quick fry appetizer. Put them on skewers, baste with a peanut ginger sauce, sauté or grill and serve while everything else is cooking.